# break in side for loop -after break statement not printing anything outside the for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, conditional-statements, break

Why doesn't the following for loop does not execute beyond 1st iteration
  can anyone help me out regarding this.
  Thanks in Advance.

The Output:

> Enter the Range of Numbers
>
> Enter the First Number: 2
>
> Enter the Last Number: 30
>
> The non-prime numbers between 2 and 30 are:
>
> .start for loop...............i=2
>
> .p....=3
>
> end of for loop: i....=2
>
> .start for loop...............i=3

AFTER THIS THE FOR LOOP DOES NOT EXECUTE ANY MORE. WHY?

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    int start, end, i, remain, k, p, count = 0;
    printf("\nEnter the Range of Numbers\n\n");
    printf("Enter the First Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &start);
    printf("Enter the Last Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &end);

    int flag;
    printf("The non-prime numbers between %d and %d are:\n", start, end);
    for (i = start; i <= end; i++)
    {
        printf("\n.start for loop...............i=%d\n", i);
        // p = 2;
        for (p = 2; p<i;)
        {
            remain = i%p;
            if (remain == 0)
                break;
            //p++;
        }
        p++;
        printf("\n.p....=%d \n", p);

        if (i == p)
            //  if(remain==0)
        {
            printf("%d ", i);
            count++;
        }
        printf("\n end of for loop: i....=%d\n", i);
    }
    printf("\n............\n");
}
```

Comment: `p` looks like you tried to modify it inside the loop it controls, but for some reason chose to comment it out. `//p++;` - So what *inside* that loop will *ever* cause the condition `p<i` to be *false* ?

Comment: @WhozCraig incrementing p++ outside outside of for (p = 2; p<i;)

Comment: You're incrementing it now outside *the entire loop*. I.e. if that loop is ever entered where (a) `p < i` and (b) `i%p != 0`, it is infinite. Neither the for loop conditional, nor any break conditions inside, will cause the loop to break; **ever**. Run this is a debugger, single step through that loop. It will show what I'm describing.

Comment: When `i` is 2, the loop is `for (p=2; p<2;)` so the loop is skipped. When `i` is 3, the loop is `for(p=2; p<3;)` which is an infinite loop.

Comment: @user3386109 i think that after  "When i is 2, the loop is for (p=2; p<2;) so the loop is skipped."  after that p++ should make p=3 (it also prints out so)

Comment: It should be 3 but you're hardcoding the value 2 in this line `for (p = 2; p<i;)` which makes p equal to 2 again.

Comment: Try putting `printf("i=%d p=%d\n",i,p);` before the line `remain = i%p;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code for loop

```
    for (p = 2; p<i;)
    {
        remain = i%p;
        if (remain == 0)
            break;
        //p++;
    }
```

is incomplete.

`p` not changeable in the `for` statement and `p++` in the body is commented. As a result you will probably have infinite loop.

Consider the following change:

```
    remain = 1;
    for (p = 2; p<i && remain; p++)
    {
        remain = i % p;
    }
```

or even (without `remain`)

```
for (p = 2; p < i && i%p; p++);
```

Comment: @ @VolAndit seems that it runs into an infinite loop. Thanks you your help.

Answer (score 0):

Let consider that `p = 2` and `i = 5`. Then what happens in this loop

```
for (p = 2; p<i;)
    {
        remain = i%p;
        if (remain == 0)
            break;
        //p++;
    }
```

1st line >> its run the for loop.
2nd line >> `remain = i%p`. i = 5 & p = 2. so remain = 5%2 = 1.
3rd line >> remain is not ZERO. so the `if(remain == 0)` return false.
and then its start its works again from the first line. So this loop is work like a infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
int start, end, i, remain, k, p, count = 0;
printf("\nEnter the Range of Numbers\n\n");
printf("Enter the First Number: ");
scanf_s("%d", &start);
printf("Enter the Last Number: ");
scanf_s("%d", &end);


int flag;
printf("The non-prime numbers between %d and %d are:\n", start, end);
for (i = start; i <= end; i++)
{
    //printf("\n.start for loop...............i=%d\n", i);
    for (p=1;p<i;p++) 
    {
        if (p > 1 && i%p == 0) 
        {
            printf("%d ", i);
            count++;
            break;
        }
    }
    //printf("\n end of for loop: i...............d\n", i);
}
printf("\n............\n");
```

It retains what I assume you're trying to do. I've commented the noise of the print statements and there is the `count++` which doesn't seem to be used anywhere. You could reduce the `for` loop to:

```
printf("The non-prime numbers between %d and %d are:\n", start, end);
for (i = start; i <= end; i++)
{
    for (p=1;p<i;p++) 
    {
        if (p > 1 && i%p == 0) 
        {
            printf("%d ", i); 
            break;
        }
    }
}
printf("\n............\n");
```

Comment: @@Ashwin Nair thanks for your help, but basically trying to print the composite numbers

Comment: @kumar, it's fixed now. Was looking for prime numbers earlier. Looking for composite numbers now.